# subsetting a file for correct chromosomes

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have an input file some of it's contents are below

```
chr1    12227   12612
chr1_ett    12721   13220
chr1    14829   14969
chr2    15038   15795
chr2_tdr    15947   16606
chr1    16765   16857
chr1    17055   17232
chr1    17368   17605
chr3    17742   17914
chr3_urr    18061   18267
```

I want to remove those lines which have `"_"` (underscore) in the first column. So basically keeping chr1,chr2,chr3 only and not chr1_ chr2_ chr3_ etc
Chromosomes goes from chr1 through chr22 and has chrX chrY and chrM.

How can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: you need to delete all lines with _?

Comment: delete those lines with _ in column 1

Comment: By the way, we now have a new SE site, [bioinformatics.se]! You might want to ask this sort of question there in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
awk '$1 !~ /_/' input_file.txt > output.txt
```

this will select all lines where `$1` (first column) does not contains `_`

or, as per Glenn Jackmann sugestion

```
awk '! index($1,"_") ' input_file.txt > output.txt
```

another way might be

```
sed -i -e '/^chr[0-9]*_/d' file.txt
```

this will delete same line. (provided line start exactly with `chr`)

Comment: `awk 'index($1, "_") == 0'` also works.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/_/d' file
```

will delete all lines where underscore appears *anywhere in the line*.

If you need to save the results back to the file, used `sed -i ...`

---

To restrict to the first column:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]\+_/d' file
```

That is: at the beginning of the line, optionally leading spaces, followed by non-space characters and an underscore.

Comment: Hi this works for my current input file, but what if I have 4th column which has underscore, so can sed be used to only delete lines where column 1 has underscore?

Comment: Yes, but it's uglier than awk. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or with `grep`:

```
grep -v "_" file
```

`-v, --invert-match` Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

To delete line if only "_" in the first column:

```
grep -v "^chr[0-9]_" file
```

Comment: this overshoots the spec: "remove those lines which have "_" (underscore) in the *first column*" by removing lines that have an underscore *anywhere* in the line

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ane 'print unless $F[0] =~ /_/' < input > output
```